# Change line number format with line-number-mode

Tags: terminal-emacs, line-numbers

With `linum-mode`, you could change how the line numbers appears by customizing `linum-format`.

`line-number-mode` appears to have replaced linum-mode, and indeed it is better (for one thing, it correctly right aligns the line numbers). However, I can't find any formatting options.

What I would like to do is

- Remove the empty space before the line number
- Replace the space after the line number with `⎢`.

(Note that I use terminal emacs)

I used to do this by setting `linum-format` to `%d⎢`.

If there aren't any formatting options, can I at least remove the left vertical column and change the character used, or if that's not possible, set a face for the right one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a closely related question [How to change line-number gutter width using display-line-numbers mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/52269/2287) , I wrote up an answer essentially stating that there is no user option to configure the left/right padding for the built-in line numbers.  This is written into the C internals of Emacs in the file `xdisp.c`.  The *left* padding of the built-in line numbers is controlled by the line of code that reads `pint2str (lnum_buf, it->lnum_width + 1, lnum_to_display);` (i.e., the `+ 1` creates the left space); and, the *right* padding is controlled by the line of code that reads `strcat (lnum_buf, " ");`

I felt that the idea of having a user option was worth pursuing and I raised this issue on the Emacs Devel mailing list, including, but not limited to some proof-concept screenshots.  The screenshots that I generated appear to be exactly what the O.P. is proposing in the question of this current thread:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2019-08/msg00418.html

The lead maintainer/developer (Eli Z.), who created the built-in line numbers of `xdisp.c`, opted not to pursue this idea for the reasons stated in the thread:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2019-08/msg00426.html

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much. Maybe one could somehow change the right space character to something else by finding and editing the memory. I don't know how to post in that thread, but I would note that the extra space is significant in terminal emacs. It can make the difference between a horizontally split window fitting 80 characters of text or not, even with the terminal full screen, (I tend to keep my font size larger so I can read things comfortably).  Of course, being in a document with over 1000 lines can also make that difference, but I consider that to be an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: I guess the question now is, how hard is it to make a pure elisp version of line-number-mode? linum-mode has the alignment issue I mentioned. I'm not sure about the performance differences. I never noticed problems with linum-mode, but I have it always on, so it's possible I did see problems but never knew that was what was causing it.

Comment: In the initial post to the Emacs Devel mailing list described above, I changed `pint2str (lnum_buf, it->lnum_width + 1, lnum_to_display);` to `pint2str (lnum_buf, it->lnum_width, lnum_to_display);` and I changed `strcat (lnum_buf, " ");` to `strcat (lnum_buf, "|");` -- the screenshots were taken after making those changes and rebuilding from source.  I am using languages that read from left to right (English and Spanish), so the `|` falls between the line numbers and the text.  I used Lisp line numbers for years before the built-in line numbers written in C -- the C version is much quicker.

Comment: In one of my rough drafts, I changed `pint2str (lnum_buf, it->lnum_width + 1, lnum_to_display);` to `pint2str (lnum_buf, it->lnum_width, lnum_to_display);` and I commented out `strcat (lnum_buf, " ");` -- resulting in no space/padding on the left and no space/padding on the right.  In my own custom setup used currently, I opted to eliminate the space on the left and keep the space on the right, without using any special character like the `|` symbol, because word-wrapped lines would need some extra coding to insert a `|` symbol on those lines where no line number exists.