# How to separate line numbers from text when using global-display-line-numbers-mode?

Tags: line-numbers

Trying `global-display-line-numbers-mode`, I would like to achieve what `linum-format` does with:
[Linum: Separating line numbers from text](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#h5o-8)

How to achieve that using `global-display-line-numbers-mode`?

Comment: The space between the built-in line numbers and the text is hard-coded in `xdisp.c`, at the line that read `strcat (lnum_buf, " ");` The deprecated Lisp version used the fringe as a separator, but that is not the case with built-in line numbers.

Comment: The question appears to be a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/55752/2287  However, I haven't studied the code in `xdisp.c` for a few years and am not caught up on the latest developments.